# Is there a way to order the QZ(or Gen. Schur) decomposition in mathematica?

Tags: functions, function-construction, linear-algebra

Let's imagine I have two matrices $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$.

The `SchurDecomposition` function in mathematica will return matrices $Q,\Lambda, Z, \Omega$, such that $Q \Lambda Z^*=\Gamma_0$ and $Q \Omega Z^*=\Gamma_1$.

However, I'm wondering if I could reorder the system, by the respective generalised eigenvalues.

Is there an in-built option, or do I have to do it from scratch?

For example, if $\lambda_{ii},\omega_{ii}$ are the main diagonal elements of $\Lambda, \Omega$ , how could I reorder the matrices $Q,Z$ such that for a constant upper bound $\bar c$ and $i\leq k$, we have $|\frac{\omega_{ii}}{\lambda_{ii}}|< \bar c $, and for the remaining $i>k$ we have $|\frac{\omega_{ii}}{\lambda_{ii}}|\geq \bar c $.

If from scratch, can someone give me a pointer in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Could check section 4.5 (Reordering) of [this 3xM article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2424796_Reordered_Schur_factorization_method_for_zero-dimensional_polynomial_systems_with_multiple_roots)